# Can a search result TextHighlighter or TextRange be bound to a DataTemplate in UWP XAML?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, binding

I have a `SearchResult` class that binds to a `ListView`. What I want to do specifically is highlight the snippet inside the search result text that matches the query the user entered.

The relevant XAML looks something like this (omitting the fluff):

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
      <!-- Search result -->
      <RichTextBlock>
         <!-- Would this idea work? -->
         <RichTextBlock.TextHighlighters>
            <TextHighlighter>
               <TextHighlighter.Ranges>
                  <!-- Add the bound range here-->
                  <!-- {Binding Range} or text highlighter or something -->
               </TextHighlighter.Ranges>
            </TextHighlighter>
         </RichTextBlock.TextHighlighters>
         <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="{Binding Text}"></Run>
         </Paragraph>
      </RichTextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I can add whatever property from the `SearchResult` class, be it a `TextHighlighter` or a `TextRange`. I just don't know whether the XAML syntax allows plugging in that value.

I've also thought of doing this in code, but I do want to keep the search item template inside the XAML, and not put it in C#. However, it would be possible to do something like `lvSearchResults.Items[i]...` or whatever it takes to put in the highlighter or range. I just can't figure out the correct method at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to create a locally highlighted search result list, you can try this way:

1. Create a search result class

```cs
public class SearchResult
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string HighlightText { get; set; }
}
```

2. Create a `UserControl` to show the result

**SearchResultBlock.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ResultBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLines="2"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
</Grid>
```

**SearchResultBlock.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class SearchResultBlock : UserControl
{
    public SearchResultBlock()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    public SearchResult Result
    {
        get { return (SearchResult)GetValue(ResultProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResultProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Result", typeof(SearchResult), typeof(SearchResultBlock), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(Result_Changed

    private static void Result_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewValue!=null && e.NewValue is SearchResult data)
        {
            var instance = d as SearchResultBlock;
            instance.ResultBlock.Inlines.Clear();
            var sp = data.DisplayText.Split(data.HighlightText);
            instance.ResultBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = sp.First() });
            instance.ResultBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = data.HighlightText, Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
            if (sp.Length > 1)
                instance.ResultBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = sp.Last() });
        }
    }
}
```

3. Use it in `DataTemplate`

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="SearchResult" x:Key="ResultItemTemplate">
    <SearchResultBlock Result="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

By string splitting, create different types of `Run`s and merge them in the `TextBlock`. This can also achieve the highlighting effect.

Best regards.